# Prove $S_K / K$ converges to zero where $S_K = ( 2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,...)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $S_K$ be the sequence listing each even number n, n times in increasing order. I.e. $(2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,10,. . .)$

Prove that the sequence $S_K/K$ converges to zero.

I can't figure out a closed form to describe $S_K$ by, I also thought about using some sequence $D_K$ which dominates $S_K$ but can't think of a suitable example.

Comment: Note that as $K$ becomes larger, the sequence tends to constancy. Furthermore, $S_K$ increases always by $2$ whereas $K$ increases in the same range by an increasing value. Thus $K$ grows faster than $S_K,$ and the limit of the ratio $S_K/K$ must be $0.$

Answer (score 0):

The first time $2n$ comes is $1$ place after $2+4+\cdots+2(n-1)$ terms. Thus, the value $2n$ comes for the first time at term:
$$2+4+\cdots+2(n-1)=2 \cdot \frac{(n-1)n}{2}=(n-1)n$$
and we have for $k=(n-1)n+1$:
$$\frac{S_k}{k}= \frac{2n}{(n-1)n+1}$$
Moreover, for any other $S_k=2n$, the denominator is only decreasing. Also, we can see easily that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n}{(n-1)n+1}=0 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_k}{k}=0$$